# How to assign a custom link to the CMS page In Magento

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I am having problem in assigning the URL in topmenu.phtml for a cMS page...
What i am doing is 
      ***FILE topmenu.phtml***

```
      <?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="topnav">


                                <li class="current"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/navigation_breaker.jpg'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                    <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/navigation_breaker.jpg'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cafe Motif</a></li>
                                    <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/navigation_breaker.jpg'); ?>" alt=""/></li>

             <?php //echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

1. I made a New page in CMS name as testing, and i want to give its link to the HOME, What should i do. Any link in 'href'

I Will be thankful.

Comment: Are you creating custom phtml file or CMS page from backend ?

Comment: I am making CMS page from backend.

Comment: you have created cms page from backend and want to show on top menu on fron side ? right

Comment: yes i want to access the CMS page by using its URL Key in topmenu of front side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok there are different  ways to  do it .First create CMS page from admin  side and pick the url-key value .Goto `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml` and open the phtml file.
If you want to insert your link at the end of top menu just paste this code ( `<li><a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl()?>put url keyhere">test page</a></li>`) at the end of foreach loop.

2) After CMS page creation go to `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml` and put this code after the    tag.

```
 <reference name="top.links"> 
     <action method="addLink" translate="label title"><label>Test</label><url>test</url><title>Test</title><prepare>true</prepare><urlParams/><position>95</position></action> 
      </reference>.
```

If you are using default theme.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, I had done it by adding url like this a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('test'); ?>">Home</a>
And i am not using the default theme, i am making custom theme.

Comment: thats nice to help you.but your way of adding link will not work when you change theme.so addlink always by action code.